# Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения по кнопке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть **json**-файл, в котором лежат объявления. Как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял эти объявления при нажатии кнопки.

Comment: Сделайте кнопку, сделайте функцию, которая отправляет объявления (с помощью `def`). К кнопке привяжите эту функцию.

Comment: Как это можно это более правильно реализовать, через какие библиотеки или встроенные методы ?

Comment: А для этого почитайте например вот [тут](https://mastergroosha.github.io/telegram-tutorial-2/buttons/)

Comment: Хорошо, но как реализовать функцию обновления

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду?

Comment: Выше вы сказали сделать функцию, которая отправляет объявления и привязать ее к кнопке. Какая логика будет у этой функции, что она должна сделать первым, вторым, а что вообще не должна делать ?

Comment: Еще бы хотел добавить, что у объявлений есть id, может через них можно как это реализовать ?

Comment: Вы же можете скопировать **json**-файл в **txt**?

Comment: Какие обновления, кому их отправлять, как эти обновления выглядят, статические или динамические?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Скопируйте текст **json**-файла и вставьте в **txt**-файл;
2. В текстовом файле у вас должны быть объявления через три запятых(,,,);
3. Вот код функции:

```
s=0
#это было начало вашей программы
test=open('Ваш файл')
r=test.read().split('},')
test.close()
{отправить сообщение}(f'{r[s]};\n')
s+=1
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131937/discussion-on-answer-by---3-8------).